# Addition of Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain $a,b\in R$ with $a$ not equal to $0$.

We know $(a)+(b)$ is an ideal of $R$.

Suppose that $\gcd(a,b)=1$, show that $(a)+(b)=R$.

Comment: What is your definition of $\gcd$?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: In a PID the gcd(a,b) is (up to an invertible factor) determined as the generator of ideal (a,b).

Comment: @hardmath: *I* know what the GCD is, thanks. I want to know what the OP calls "gcd", because there are a few equivalent definitions, and for example with your definition the question is completely trivial ($(a)+(b) = (a,b) = (1) = R$).

Comment: i had it set to hfc(a,b)=1 where 1 is the largest integer that divides both a and b. Someone has edited this to gcd(a,b)

Comment: The notion of "largest integer" is suspect, since $R$ is not assumed to be $\mathbb{Z}$.  Of greater application would be a condition that every divisor (or factor) of both $a,b$ is a divisor of $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Bézout's identity holds in every PID, not only in $\mathbb{Z}$.

To be more explicit: $(a)+(b)=(c)$ for a $c\in R$, since every ideal in $R$ is a prinicipal ideal. We now see that $a,b\in(c)$, hence $c$ divides both $a$ and $b$ and therefore also $c \vert \gcd(a,b)=1$. Now we see, that $c$ is a unit of $R$ and $(c)=(1)=R$.

Comment: This identity is not covered in my course, hence i have to prove this without but thanks anyway

Comment: how do we see that a,b ∈ (c)

Comment: We have $(a)+(b)=\lbrace x+y | x\in (a), y\in (b)\rbrace$. Since $a\in (a)$ and $0\in (b)$ it is $a=a+0\in (a)+(b)$; analogously for $b$.